# Limit of ratio of sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a$ and $b \neq 0$ be real numbers and $x_n$ and $y_n$ be sequences such that $\lim x_n=a$ and $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}=b$. Show that $\lim y_n=\frac{a}{b}$

Can't work this one out, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

My attempt:

Using $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}=b$, I have $\lim\frac{x_n-by_n}{y_n}=0$. Then I tried to show that $\frac{1}{y_n}$ does not go to zero, but I failed to do so, and I think that is not necessarily true since a could be 0 and b cound still be not 0. I tried usind the $\epsilon$ definitions and couldn't work that out either

Comment: You need to include your attempt. Users here are sometimes penalized for answering this type of no-attempt question.

Comment: It's a direct application of the [limit of ratio of two sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties), provided that the denominator $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}=b\ne 0$.

Comment: @peterwhy The limit of ratio of sequences has the assumption that the sequences converge. Here I do not know if $y_n$ converges

Comment: Both the numerator $\lim x_n$ and the denominator $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ are given to converge here.

Comment: Oh, you're saying that I should use that $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\frac{x_n}{y_n}}$. That's clever, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=a$, we can rewrite $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ as $a\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1{y_n}$ which is just $b$. Dividing both sides by $a$ and taking the reciprocal we get the answer.